# Executing an Oracle stored procedure with a output parameter of a complex type using php adodb library

Tags: php, oracle, stored-procedures, parameters, plsql

Using the following code I get an error stating invalid number of parameters.

```
        $stmt = $this->db->PrepareSP("DECLARE SONUC VREPORT_ARRAY; BEGIN ZDS.ADMIN_REPORT(:SORGU_TARIH,:SONUC); END;");
        $this->db->InParameter($stmt,$DATA['SORGU_TARIH'],'SORGU_TARIH');
        $this->db->OutParameter($stmt,$output,'SONUC');
        $rs = $this->db->Execute($stmt);
```

The second parameter named SONUC is of VARRAY / TABLE type. I cannot be sure whether this kind of return type is unsopperted or I'm missing something else. I'm using adodb library for database operations.

Edit: The following is the error message I got running the procedure call.

```
oci8 error: [6550: ORA-06550: line 1, column 36: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'ADMIN_REPORT' ORA-06550: line 1, column 36: PL/SQL: Statement ignored] in EXECUTE("Array")
```

Edit 2: After a ton of trials and wasted hours, it is still not working. The application has other statements calling stored procedures successfully (none of them have a return output parameter) . They are all executed through Execute method directly. PrepareSP and InParameter/OutParameter was never used.

Comment: Is the error generated by PHP interpreter or Oracle?

Comment: @George It is an oci exception actually, the procedure runs and produces output when called from TOAD.

Comment: Can you post a bit more code? For example, the values of `$DATA['SORGU_TARIH']` and `$output`.

Comment: $DATA['SORGU_TARIH'] = '20130401' is date in reverse basically just a string. $output is declared and used as is. No initial value. It is supposed to be assigned to the return value.

Comment: Does the code for `ZDS.ADMIN_REPORT` include the correct IN/OUT parameter identifier? It would be helpful if you posted the function declaration or the line referenced by the error.

Comment: there should be an `ORA` error, give us that number.

Comment: @RubyLovely Edit: The following is the error message I got running the procedure call.

    oci8 error: [6550: ORA-06550: line 1, column 36: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'ADMIN_REPORT' ORA-06550: line 1, column 36: PL/SQL: Statement ignored] in EXECUTE("Array")